# Two column drop-down without table

Tags: html, css

I want to make this drop-down menu:

```
       |  Heading
----------------
action |  Item
action |  Item
action |  Item
action |  Item
```

`action` could be "Change" and `Item` could be something like "Users". Semantically it would make sense to have this HTML:

```
<h3>Heading</h3>
<dl>
  <dt>action</dt>
    <dd>Item</dd>
  <dt>action</dt>
    <dd>Item</dd>
</dl>
```

But as far as I know, there is no way to make the action and Item align, as we don't want fixed heights or widths.

The obvious would be to use a `<table/>`, but since this isn't tabular data, it's pretty ugly. Can I create this design without using a HTML table? Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you limit the width of a `ul` and float the `li`'s to left, you could achieve what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/cudNX/

Comment: @Lollero: Sorry, I can't limit the width, need it to be dynamic.

Comment: I can easily undertand why youd want the height to be dynamic but why width?

Comment: @Lollero: I want it to look like the first "illustration" above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you have to use a `<table>`. Until someone suggests something else

Answer (score 1):

You can actually align `dt` and `dd` with `float:left` like this:

```
dt {
  float:left;   
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUmXk/)

Comment: Hi thanks, I think I need to clarify one thing: I need it to be stretchable, like a table is. And I need the "columns" to align vertically and horizontally. In you Fiddle, if you change the first "action" to "longer action", I need both `<dt>` to be of the same width, which they are not.

Answer (score 0):

ok so heres how its going to work

```
<ul>

<li>
    <span class="action">"Put Action Here"</>
    <span class="item>"Put Item Here"</>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="action">"Put Action Here"</>
    <span class="item>"Put Item Here"</>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="action">"Put Action Here"</>
    <span class="item>"Put Item Here"</>
</li>

</ul>
```

and then in CSS you can position them:

```
.action {float:left;}
.item {float:right;}
```

Just tried it on Fiddle and it worked beautifully!

Comment: I guess this breaks down if .action and .item are not the same height?

Comment: @Znarkus Make it the same height--- that way we are all happy.. Instead of using `span`  try using `div` and make them both same height -- you might have to work a bit to get the alignment correct by it will get there.

Comment: From the question: "But as far as I know, there is no way to make the action and Item align, as we don't want fixed heights or widths."

Comment: @Znarkus well - if you dont want fixed widths,  then you are going to have to use tables...